# RSA signature in Java and verify in C#

Tags: java, c#, security, hash, signature

I'm working in an internet security project where I have to implement a scheme to communicate public keys between two entities using a Third trusted party (called Trent). My two entities are developed in C# and Trent is developed in Java. A needs to get B's public key through Trent. So Trent should return B's public key and the sign of the message. The problem is that the signature done by Trent does not verify on A's side. I believe it's something to do with the hashing algorithm that Java and C# are using. These are my codes:

Trent.java

```
    public static byte[] RSASign(byte[] DataToSign, KeyPair key) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, SignatureException
    {
        Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
        sig.initSign(key.getPrivate());
        sig.update(DataToSign);
        return sig.sign();
    }
```

Entity C#

```
    public static bool RSAVerify(byte[] SignedData, byte[] DataToVerify, string publicKeyXml)
    {
        RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        rsa.FromXmlString(publicKeyXml);
        return rsa.VerifyData(DataToVerify, new SHA256CryptoServiceProvider(), SignedData);
    }
```

A public key XML example is as follows:

```
<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>AJLDBWyLvZk2BRhr9AHs5LlszWMOZJTvhlBVD94eCibb5PI1rmbyJ3Rs8mNGSlPn2sPZUrwAZj6/w23VIGur39g7tnSskt/+ab9k5xXdCdbWOckeBVtyksDF56dH7mLyoNxzg/msSNN8xTX8MG9VaSPnfyK35U3NQ5ePZRacsh7h</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent></RSAKeyValue>
```

Trent's public key (used to sign and verify) is created on Trent's side with the next Java code:

```
KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
keyGen.initialize(1024);
KeyPair key = keyGen.generateKeyPair();
```

Do you have any idea what's going on and, if the problem is the hashing methods used, how can I do to make them match? Thank you in advance!

---

**Update**

Next are some examples of how I'm using this code:

Java:

First, when loading the Trent, I create the KeyPair which Alice gets from a call. To get it in the XML format used by RSACryptoServiceProvider, Trent converts the String into such format using the next code:

```
public static String getPublicKeyAsXml(PublicKey publicKey) throws Exception{

   KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
   RSAPublicKeySpec ks = kf.getKeySpec(publicKey, RSAPublicKeySpec.class);
   BigInteger modulus = ks.getModulus();
   BigInteger exponent = ks.getPublicExponent();
   byte[] modByte = modulus.toByteArray();
   byte[] expByte = exponent.toByteArray();
   String encodedModulus = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(modByte);
   String encodedExponent = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(expByte);
   String publicKeyAsXML = "<RSAKeyValue>" +
                   "<Modulus>" + encodedModulus + "</Modulus>" +
                   "<Exponent>" + encodedExponent + "</Exponent>" +
                   "</RSAKeyValue>";

   return publicKeyAsXML;
}
```

When A requests B's public key, it calls a method to Trent:

```
string destinationId = "B";
string destinationPk = "pk"; //for this problem there's no need to think about B's pk
byte[] destinationIdByte = entityIdToByteArray(destinationId);
byte[] destinationPkByte = stringToByteArray(destinationPk);
byte[] plainMessage = concat(destinationIdByte, destinationPkByte);
byte[] signedMessage = RSASign(plainMessage, key); //Trent's KeyPair
return concat(signedMessage, plainMessage);
```

Some extra methods in Java:

```
public static byte[] stringToByteArray(String stringMessage)
{
    return stringMessage.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-16LE"));
}

//To have the entity id byte with a fixed length of 80 bytes.
public static byte[] entityIdToByteArray(String entityId)
{
    String toByte = padRight(entityId, 40);
    return stringToByteArray(toByte);
}

public static String padRight(String s, int n) {
    return String.format("%1$-" + n + "s", s);  
}
```

On C# side:

```
byte[] trentResponseMessage = ... //Gotten from Java Trent (Sign(PKb,Bob),PKb,Bob) --> (128,486,80) bytes
byte[] signedMessage = new byte[128];
Array.Copy(trentResponseMessage, 0, signedMessage, 0, signedMessage.Length);
byte[] plainMessage = new byte[566];
Array.Copy(trentResponseMessage, 128, plainMessage, 0, plainMessage.Length);

string trentpk = ...; //The one gotten from Java Trent before
if (!KeyManager.RSAVerify(signedMessage, plainMessage, trentpk))
{
    Console.WriteLine("The signature does not verify!");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Trent signature verified!");
}
```

The array lengths I'm receiving on A's side are correct, and the strings from the plainMessage are received correctly as well. It's just the sign verification that is returning false.

As extra comments, I'm using .NET Framework 4.6.1.

---

**Update 2**

These are the prints from the strings and bytes being signed and sent to A.

Java side:

```
destinationPk: <RSAKeyValue><Modulus>6zcQeWcA54cICsP3tcGY7XTASUWYJuxWsfAeuVC+5By5jxfGeuIBJ0Q8otaM0YJ1OYQ9dMetE/DGMybY88TabDrDN++/d1wgG8fASl0OPkPP3c31SpOgf/NrZVKYg0F+EyltjuUsKZh7m4pzlzDAV+fI0u4rGmrgjpCJdCznjgk=</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent></RSAKeyValue>
destinationId: http://localhost:1111/Bob
destinationIdByte: [104,0,116,0,116,0,112,0,58,0,47,0,47,0,108,0,111,0,99,0,97,0,108,0,104,0,111,0,115,0,116,0,58,0,49,0,49,0,49,0,49,0,47,0,66,0,111,0,98,0,32,0,32,0,32,0,32,0,32,0,32,0,32,0,32,0,32,0,32,0,32,0,32,0,32,0,32,0,32,0]
destinationPkByte: [60,0,82,0,83,0,65,0,75,0,101,0,121,0,86,0,97,0,108,0,117,0,101,0,62,0,60,0,77,0,111,0,100,0,117,0,108,0,117,0,115,0,62,0,119,0,112,0,65,0,98,0,43,0,88,0,71,0,112,0,100,0,98,0,114,0,101,0,102,0,68,0,101,0,47,0,55,0,78,0,118,0,77,0,117,0,69,0,83,0,97,0,122,0,56,0,116,0,105,0,84,0,110,0,87,0,66,0,88,0,56,0,82,0,57,0,97,0,117,0,121,0,48,0,78,0,82,0,67,0,113,0,112,0,48,0,76,0,85,0,107,0,50,0,73,0,85,0,72,0,105,0,73,0,69,0,120,0,78,0,55,0,65,0,77,0,56,0,119,0,80,0,69,0,75,0,68,0,88,0,87,0,116,0,117,0,73,0,55,0,77,0,52,0,88,0,119,0,107,0,81,0,71,0,49,0,66,0,84,0,109,0,80,0,79,0,70,0,77,0,121,0,103,0,70,0,48,0,69,0,122,0,69,0,51,0,98,0,121,0,88,0,121,0,54,0,90,0,114,0,100,0,69,0,115,0,48,0,69,0,112,0,82,0,71,0,110,0,52,0,72,0,78,0,80,0,88,0,98,0,75,0,48,0,76,0,109,0,48,0,104,0,106,0,101,0,85,0,97,0,121,0,48,0,106,0,121,0,103,0,98,0,112,0,89,0,71,0,55,0,120,0,71,0,77,0,121,0,97,0,80,0,84,0,47,0,79,0,74,0,113,0,74,0,69,0,73,0,112,0,111,0,88,0,49,0,86,0,114,0,52,0,69,0,51,0,83,0,85,0,122,0,103,0,111,0,90,0,76,0,43,0,118,0,85,0,61,0,60,0,47,0,77,0,111,0,100,0,117,0,108,0,117,0,115,0,62,0,60,0,69,0,120,0,112,0,111,0,110,0,101,0,110,0,116,0,62,0,65,0,81,0,65,0,66,0,60,0,47,0,69,0,120,0,112,0,111,0,110,0,101,0,110,0,116,0,62,0,60,0,47,0,82,0,83,0,65,0,75,0,101,0,121,0,86,0,97,0,108,0,117,0,101,0,62,0]
plainMessage (bytes): [60,0,82,0,83,0,65,0,75,0,101,0,121,0,86,0,97,0,108,0,117,0,101,0,62,0,60,0,77,0,111,0,100,0,117,0,108,0,117,0,115,0,62,0,54,0,122,0,99,0,81,0,101,0,87,0,99,0,65,0,53,0,52,0,99,0,73,0,67,0,115,0,80,0,51,0,116,0,99,0,71,0,89,0,55,0,88,0,84,0,65,0,83,0,85,0,87,0,89,0,74,0,117,0,120,0,87,0,115,0,102,0,65,0,101,0,117,0,86,0,67,0,43,0,53,0,66,0,121,0,53,0,106,0,120,0,102,0,71,0,101,0,117,0,73,0,66,0,74,0,48,0,81,0,56,0,111,0,116,0,97,0,77,0,48,0,89,0,74,0,49,0,79,0,89,0,81,0,57,0,100,0,77,0,101,0,116,0,69,0,47,0,68,0,71,0,77,0,121,0,98,0,89,0,56,0,56,0,84,0,97,0,98,0,68,0,114,0,68,0,78,0,43,0,43,0,47,0,100,0,49,0,119,0,103,0,71,0,56,0,102,0,65,0,83,0,108,0,48,0,79,0,80,0,107,0,80,0,80,0,51,0,99,0,51,0,49,0,83,0,112,0,79,0,103,0,102,0,47,0,78,0,114,0,90,0,86,0,75,0,89,0,103,0,48,0,70,0,43,0,69,0,121,0,108,0,116,0,106,0,117,0,85,0,115,0,75,0,90,0,104,0,55,0,109,0,52,0,112,0,122,0,108,0,122,0,68,0,65,0,86,0,43,0,102,0,73,0,48,0,117,0,52,0,114,0,71,0,109,0,114,0,103,0,106,0,112,0,67,0,74,0,100,0,67,0,122,0,110,0,106,0,103,0,107,0,61,0,60,0,47,0,77,0,111,0,100,0,117,0,108,0,117,0,115,0,62,0,60,0,69,0,120,0,112,0,111,0,110,0,101,0,110,0,116,0,62,0,65,0,81,0,65,0,66,0,60,0,47,0,69,0,120,0,112,0,111,0,110,0,101,0,110,0,116,0,62,0,60,0,47,0,82,0,83,0,65,0,75,0,101,0,121,0,86,0,97,0,108,0,117,0,101,0,62,0,104,0,116,0,116,0,112,0,58,0,47,0,47,0,108,0,111,0,99,0,97,0,108,0,104,0,111,0,115,0,116,0,58,0,49,0,49,0,49,0,49,0,47,0,66,0,111,0,98,0,32,0,32,0,32,0,32,0,32,0,32,0,32,0,32,0,32,0,32,0,32,0,32,0,32,0,32,0,32,0]
signedMessage (bytes): [153,253,158,106,41,164,114,244,163,79,65,143,204,164,143,135,4,30,210,218,152,189,175,68,40,226,132,226,0,147,176,73,42,139,239,224,142,217,95,3,36,69,233,107,255,89,56,220,123,248,20,214,192,156,212,106,61,125,166,173,165,244,165,245,40,215,78,248,86,251,115,47,83,139,158,75,229,251,97,81,48,87,0,182,65,141,57,154,46,219,222,100,127,38,222,250,54,218,19,204,45,159,223,217,65,33,81,35,65,104,45,11,214,33,29,76,255,85,3,90,213,164,152,79,76,154,16,59]
Whole message sent to A:[153,253,158,106,41,164,114,244,163,79,65,143,204,164,143,135,4,30,210,218,152,189,175,68,40,226,132,226,0,147,176,73,42,139,239,224,142,217,95,3,36,69,233,107,255,89,56,220,123,248,20,214,192,156,212,106,61,125,166,173,165,244,165,245,40,215,78,248,86,251,115,47,83,139,158,75,229,251,97,81,48,87,0,182,65,141,57,154,46,219,222,100,127,38,222,250,54,218,19,204,45,159,223,217,65,33,81,35,65,104,45,11,214,33,29,76,255,85,3,90,213,164,152,79,76,154,16,59,60,0,82,0,83,0,65,0,75,0,101,0,121,0,86,0,97,0,108,0,117,0,101,0,62,0,60,0,77,0,111,0,100,0,117,0,108,0,117,0,115,0,62,0,54,0,122,0,99,0,81,0,101,0,87,0,99,0,65,0,53,0,52,0,99,0,73,0,67,0,115,0,80,0,51,0,116,0,99,0,71,0,89,0,55,0,88,0,84,0,65,0,83,0,85,0,87,0,89,0,74,0,117,0,120,0,87,0,115,0,102,0,65,0,101,0,117,0,86,0,67,0,43,0,53,0,66,0,121,0,53,0,106,0,120,0,102,0,71,0,101,0,117,0,73,0,66,0,74,0,48,0,81,0,56,0,111,0,116,0,97,0,77,0,48,0,89,0,74,0,49,0,79,0,89,0,81,0,57,0,100,0,77,0,101,0,116,0,69,0,47,0,68,0,71,0,77,0,121,0,98,0,89,0,56,0,56,0,84,0,97,0,98,0,68,0,114,0,68,0,78,0,43,0,43,0,47,0,100,0,49,0,119,0,103,0,71,0,56,0,102,0,65,0,83,0,108,0,48,0,79,0,80,0,107,0,80,0,80,0,51,0,99,0,51,0,49,0,83,0,112,0,79,0,103,0,102,0,47,0,78,0,114,0,90,0,86,0,75,0,89,0,103,0,48,0,70,0,43,0,69,0,121,0,108,0,116,0,106,0,117,0,85,0,115,0,75,0,90,0,104,0,55,0,109,0,52,0,112,0,122,0,108,0,122,0,68,0,65,0,86,0,43,0,102,0,73,0,48,0,117,0,52,0,114,0,71,0,109,0,114,0,103,0,106,0,112,0,67,0,74,0,100,0,67,0,122,0,110,0,106,0,103,0,107,0,61,0,60,0,47,0,77,0,111,0,100,0,117,0,108,0,117,0,115,0,62,0,60,0,69,0,120,0,112,0,111,0,110,0,101,0,110,0,116,0,62,0,65,0,81,0,65,0,66,0,60,0,47,0,69,0,120,0,112,0,111,0,110,0,101,0,110,0,116,0,62,0,60,0,47,0,82,0,83,0,65,0,75,0,101,0,121,0,86,0,97,0,108,0,117,0,101,0,62,0,104,0,116,0,116,0,112,0,58,0,47,0,47,0,108,0,111,0,99,0,97,0,108,0,104,0,111,0,115,0,116,0,58,0,49,0,49,0,49,0,49,0,47,0,66,0,111,0,98,0,32,0,32,0,32,0,32,0,32,0,32,0,32,0,32,0,32,0,32,0,32,0,32,0,32,0,32,0,32,0]
```

C# side

```
Trent message received (bytes): [153,253,158,106,41,164,114,244,163,79,65,143,204,164,143,135,4,30,210,218,152,189,175,68,40,226,132,226,0,147,176,73,42,139,239,224,142,217,95,3,36,69,233,107,255,89,56,220,123,248,20,214,192,156,212,106,61,125,166,173,165,244,165,245,40,215,78,248,86,251,115,47,83,139,158,75,229,251,97,81,48,87,0,182,65,141,57,154,46,219,222,100,127,38,222,250,54,218,19,204,45,159,223,217,65,33,81,35,65,104,45,11,214,33,29,76,255,85,3,90,213,164,152,79,76,154,16,59,60,0,82,0,83,0,65,0,75,0,101,0,121,0,86,0,97,0,108,0,117,0,101,0,62,0,60,0,77,0,111,0,100,0,117,0,108,0,117,0,115,0,62,0,119,0,112,0,65,0,98,0,43,0,88,0,71,0,112,0,100,0,98,0,114,0,101,0,102,0,68,0,101,0,47,0,55,0,78,0,118,0,77,0,117,0,69,0,83,0,97,0,122,0,56,0,116,0,105,0,84,0,110,0,87,0,66,0,88,0,56,0,82,0,57,0,97,0,117,0,121,0,48,0,78,0,82,0,67,0,113,0,112,0,48,0,76,0,85,0,107,0,50,0,73,0,85,0,72,0,105,0,73,0,69,0,120,0,78,0,55,0,65,0,77,0,56,0,119,0,80,0,69,0,75,0,68,0,88,0,87,0,116,0,117,0,73,0,55,0,77,0,52,0,88,0,119,0,107,0,81,0,71,0,49,0,66,0,84,0,109,0,80,0,79,0,70,0,77,0,121,0,103,0,70,0,48,0,69,0,122,0,69,0,51,0,98,0,121,0,88,0,121,0,54,0,90,0,114,0,100,0,69,0,115,0,48,0,69,0,112,0,82,0,71,0,110,0,52,0,72,0,78,0,80,0,88,0,98,0,75,0,48,0,76,0,109,0,48,0,104,0,106,0,101,0,85,0,97,0,121,0,48,0,106,0,121,0,103,0,98,0,112,0,89,0,71,0,55,0,120,0,71,0,77,0,121,0,97,0,80,0,84,0,47,0,79,0,74,0,113,0,74,0,69,0,73,0,112,0,111,0,88,0,49,0,86,0,114,0,52,0,69,0,51,0,83,0,85,0,122,0,103,0,111,0,90,0,76,0,43,0,118,0,85,0,61,0,60,0,47,0,77,0,111,0,100,0,117,0,108,0,117,0,115,0,62,0,60,0,69,0,120,0,112,0,111,0,110,0,101,0,110,0,116,0,62,0,65,0,81,0,65,0,66,0,60,0,47,0,69,0,120,0,112,0,111,0,110,0,101,0,110,0,116,0,62,0,60,0,47,0,82,0,83,0,65,0,75,0,101,0,121,0,86,0,97,0,108,0,117,0,101,0,62,0,104,0,116,0,116,0,112,0,58,0,47,0,47,0,108,0,111,0,99,0,97,0,108,0,104,0,111,0,115,0,116,0,58,0,49,0,49,0,49,0,49,0,47,0,66,0,111,0,98,0,32,0,32,0,32,0,32,0,32,0,32,0,32,0,32,0,32,0,32,0,32,0,32,0,32,0,32,0,32,0]
Signed part of trent message: [153,253,158,106,41,164,114,244,163,79,65,143,204,164,143,135,4,30,210,218,152,189,175,68,40,226,132,226,0,147,176,73,42,139,239,224,142,217,95,3,36,69,233,107,255,89,56,220,123,248,20,214,192,156,212,106,61,125,166,173,165,244,165,245,40,215,78,248,86,251,115,47,83,139,158,75,229,251,97,81,48,87,0,182,65,141,57,154,46,219,222,100,127,38,222,250,54,218,19,204,45,159,223,217,65,33,81,35,65,104,45,11,214,33,29,76,255,85,3,90,213,164,152,79,76,154,16,59]
Plain text part of trent message: [60,0,82,0,83,0,65,0,75,0,101,0,121,0,86,0,97,0,108,0,117,0,101,0,62,0,60,0,77,0,111,0,100,0,117,0,108,0,117,0,115,0,62,0,119,0,112,0,65,0,98,0,43,0,88,0,71,0,112,0,100,0,98,0,114,0,101,0,102,0,68,0,101,0,47,0,55,0,78,0,118,0,77,0,117,0,69,0,83,0,97,0,122,0,56,0,116,0,105,0,84,0,110,0,87,0,66,0,88,0,56,0,82,0,57,0,97,0,117,0,121,0,48,0,78,0,82,0,67,0,113,0,112,0,48,0,76,0,85,0,107,0,50,0,73,0,85,0,72,0,105,0,73,0,69,0,120,0,78,0,55,0,65,0,77,0,56,0,119,0,80,0,69,0,75,0,68,0,88,0,87,0,116,0,117,0,73,0,55,0,77,0,52,0,88,0,119,0,107,0,81,0,71,0,49,0,66,0,84,0,109,0,80,0,79,0,70,0,77,0,121,0,103,0,70,0,48,0,69,0,122,0,69,0,51,0,98,0,121,0,88,0,121,0,54,0,90,0,114,0,100,0,69,0,115,0,48,0,69,0,112,0,82,0,71,0,110,0,52,0,72,0,78,0,80,0,88,0,98,0,75,0,48,0,76,0,109,0,48,0,104,0,106,0,101,0,85,0,97,0,121,0,48,0,106,0,121,0,103,0,98,0,112,0,89,0,71,0,55,0,120,0,71,0,77,0,121,0,97,0,80,0,84,0,47,0,79,0,74,0,113,0,74,0,69,0,73,0,112,0,111,0,88,0,49,0,86,0,114,0,52,0,69,0,51,0,83,0,85,0,122,0,103,0,111,0,90,0,76,0,43,0,118,0,85,0,61,0,60,0,47,0,77,0,111,0,100,0,117,0,108,0,117,0,115,0,62,0,60,0,69,0,120,0,112,0,111,0,110,0,101,0,110,0,116,0,62,0,65,0,81,0,65,0,66,0,60,0,47,0,69,0,120,0,112,0,111,0,110,0,101,0,110,0,116,0,62,0,60,0,47,0,82,0,83,0,65,0,75,0,101,0,121,0,86,0,97,0,108,0,117,0,101,0,62,0,104,0,116,0,116,0,112,0,58,0,47,0,47,0,108,0,111,0,99,0,97,0,108,0,104,0,111,0,115,0,116,0,58,0,49,0,49,0,49,0,49,0,47,0,66,0,111,0,98,0,32,0,32,0,32,0,32,0,32,0,32,0,32,0,32,0,32,0,32,0,32,0,32,0,32,0,32,0,32,0]
```

Comment: Can you post a sample `byte[] SignedData, byte[] DataToVerify, string publicKeyXml` so we could try this? Also, what is your runtime (.net framework, mono, .net core, uwp, what versions etc)

Comment: @zaitsman thank you for your response! I updated my question :)

Comment: i meant can you post actual signed messages and plain messages that can't be verified? Java code does not help try different things on your values in c#

Comment: @zaitsman updated

Comment: i will try with this, but whenever you need to post byte arrays, it is easiest to use `Convert.ToBase64String` coz that is unambigious. the values you posted could be 10 based or 16 based, for example..

Comment: @zaitsman got it! I will bare it in mind for the next posts. Thank you! And just as an extra note, I modified the printing algorithm in Java. The signed part of the message both when sending from Java and receiving on C# is actually a match

Comment: Did you find the problem? Asking because I'm experiencing similar issues.